# Cluster sampling result in larger sample-to-sample variability

Tags: survey, survey-sampling, cluster-sample

I'm reading STATA's [Survey Data Reference Manual](https://www.stata.com/bookstore/survey-data-reference-manual).

There is written that:

> Cluster sampling typically results in larger sample-to-sample variability than sampling individuals directly.

Do you have an intuitive explanation for this statement? (I'm not looking for a mathematical proof).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we cluster sample, that is, divide the population into clusters (such as households or towns), we have an issue that subjects in a particular cluster are likely to be similar on the measure. This means that weird results are more likely.

For example, suppose we are measuring height of adult males. A particular cluster may have a lot of very tall men.

Cluster sampling is, nevertheless, sometimes a good option because, e.g. it can be much cheaper per individual, and the larger sample size may make up for the less than optimal variance.

Comment: So a given sample will have *less* variability because of more similar units, meaning that repeating the experiments (with different clusters) will result in samples which are more dissimilar to each other.

Comment: But the hypothesis is that they are not, that a cluster of households is representative of the whole population, and another cluster of households is also representative of the whole population, so that the two clusters are similar between each other, where "representative" means that the distribution of covariates in the cluster is the same of the whole population. Right? Otherwise we are in the case of stratification

Comment: No, that's not the hypothesis.  

Each cluster of N people will be less representative of the whole population than N individuals randomly chosen. That's why you choose multiple clusters.  But the fact that clusters are very likely to be similar is going to increase the variance, even when you have several clusters. 

It's just that cluster sampling can be useful in other ways. 

The distributions of the sample are NEVER the same as those of the population. It's a question of how close they are and how they are wrong.